# setting up rails-timeago for locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

On Gemfile I have this following gem `gem 'rails-timeago', '~> 2.0'` and on application.js I load these scripts in this order

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ckeditor-jquery
//= require bootstrap/bootstrap
//= require rails-timeago
//= require locales/jquery.timeago.fr.js
//= require jquery.flexslider
//= require_tree .
```

On my view I'm calling timeago

```
<%= timeago_tag story.created_at, :nojs => true, :limit => 3.days.ago, :lang => :fr  %>
```

On application.html.erb

```
<%= timeago_script_tag %>
```

and On my browser I have this  result

```
  <script>
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.timeago.settings.lang="en";
//]]>
</script>
```

Even though I copy-paste this code to replace the script_tag and added `.lang="fr"` on application.html.erb, it still doesn't do the translation.

The view segments (from the browser):

```
<time data-time-ago="2014-02-24T03:04:02Z" datetime="2014-02-24T03:04:02Z" lang="fr" title="Mon, 24 Feb 2014 03:04:02 +0000">2 days</time>
```

Comment: What is your `I18n.locale` set to?

Comment: the docs say `timeago_script_tag` sets "the jQuery timeago locale according to your `I18n.locale`"

Comment: something wrong ... it's still not working. I have set `I18n.enforce_available_locales = true` and `config.i18n.default_locale = :fr`

Comment: I would recommend you try overriding this yourself in JS with `jQuery.timeago.settings.lang = "fr"`